# Why doesn't `clang -S` generate assembly code for member functions?

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

Let's say I want to get clang to show me what assembly it generates for `Node::Destroy` in the following code:

```cpp
struct Node {
  Node* next = nullptr;
  int x;

  ~Node() {
    delete next;
  }

  void Destroy() {
    delete this;
  }
};
```

If I run `clang++ -S foo.cc` then it gives essentially empty output:

```
        .text
        .file   "foo.cc"
        .ident  "Debian clang version 14.0.6-2"
        .section        ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
        .addrsig
```

But if I change `Destroy` to a free-standing function that accepts `Node*` rather than a member function, then it actually does generate assembly:

```
        .text
        .file   "foo.cc"
        .globl  _Z7DestroyP4Node                # -- Begin function _Z7DestroyP4Node
        .p2align        4, 0x90
        .type   _Z7DestroyP4Node,@function
_Z7DestroyP4Node:                       # @_Z7DestroyP4Node
        .cfi_startproc
# %bb.0:
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
        subq    $16, %rsp
        movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
[...]
```

The same is true [in compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/af46fY51c). What's the reason for this difference?

Comment: Probably because the member functions are implicitly `inline` when defined in class body.

Comment: The member functions are all dead code because you haven't called any of them, or even instantiated an object on which you could call them. Create a Node object, and invoke the member function(s) you care about, and things will change: https://godbolt.org/z/sE3zhfT8v

Comment: @JerryCoffin: sure, but I also haven't called the free-standing function. My question is why this matters for the member function but not the free-standing function. How can clang prove that the member functions are unused by other translation units, and why doesn't that work for the free-standing function? I assume HolyBlackCat is on the right path, but would like more details.

Comment: @jacobsa: yes, the member functions being inline does matter as well. The global function can be called from another file, so the compiler generates code for it, in case it might be. Since the member functions are inline, that's not true for them--they can only be invoked from a file that includes the full definition of the function. Since they're not used in this file, it doesn't have to generate code for them at all.

Comment: That totally makes sense, thanks. Indeed if I define a member function out of line (https://godbolt.org/z/neod6K7o5) it works as I expected it too. Do you want to turn that into an answer and I'll accept it?